# How to use JS Regex for getting value of query from a google query link? (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have data which has some links from browser history. What I want to do is to find out only those links which are of google queries and more specifically, only those in which queries contain a keyword `meaning`.
This is what I have tried so far.

```
function extractDataFromHistory(){
    //document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = "hi";
    chrome.history.search({text: "", maxResults: 1000}, function(historyItems){
        var data = '';
        for(var i=0; i<historyItems.length; i++){
            var url = historyItems[i].url;
            if(url.indexOf('google')>-1 && url.search('q=')){
                //data += historyItems[i].url.indexOf('google');
                data += url;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

The sample data that I get:

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_match.asp&ei=P-mtU7fgKZCzuASO6oKQAw&usg=AFQjCNHsd5ZSdXHlmUSuD1lDE1KSdvDpuw&sig2=WOxgZGk_pqssrijyyxiJRQ&bvm=bv.69837884,d.c2E

https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=js%20regex%20match

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_split.asp&ei=dOitU9fYGISWuATQwILADg&usg=AFQjCNGzLD-MIahz1yk3hWzuWpITkgNDRw&sig2=2oDeYwR7vSjZjUm-gkBJJg&bvm=bv.69837884,d.c2E

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=js+string+operations&oq=js+string+operations&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3671j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try regex:

```
'google.+q=(.+?)&'
```

The part in parenthesis is the search query.

Comment: Almost what I wanted. But this is exactly what I wanted! `google.+q=(.+?)&` Thanks Shaven

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, But there is another test case which is not being covered here. 
`https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=meaning%20of%20names` In this type of input how can I take the same output as there is no `&` afrer `q=`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an online regex tester (I used regex101.com):

Regex:
google.+q=(.*\+?meaning\+?.*)

Test:
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the+meaning+of+life&safe=off

Comment: I think this is what your looking for: q=(.*\+?meaning.*)&

What's inside the parenthesis is what gets matched.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, what above answer tells. But both answers are different still gives same results? Why?

Comment: Both answers are different, notice the second answer included the '&' at the end, and what is grouped inside of the parenthesis is a group.  I'd highly suggest playing around with the regular expressions at regex101.com, which will give you a break down of the expression.  There are other sites out there that can be used for reference as well.